Unable to connect to server through JS websocket
I have a server where a server socket accepts connections and sends no. of clients connected. I can connect to it fine with Java and Python websocket programs and it gives the desired client no. count, but JS websocket gives error.
Server code:
import socket
import threading
import time

lock = threading.Lock()
count = 0

def handle_client(c: socket.socket, addr):
    global count, lock
    while True:
        try:
            c.send(f"{count}".encode())
            time.sleep(0.5)
        except:
            print('Client disconnected: ' + addr[0])
            with lock:
                count -= 1
            break

s = socket.socket()
port = 56123
s.bind((socket.gethostname(), port))
s.listen(5)
print('Server started')
while True:
    c, addr = s.accept()
    print('Client connected: ' + addr[0])
    with lock:
        count += 1
    threading.Thread(target=handle_client, args=(c, addr,)).start()

Python client code:
import socket
import time

s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(('server.com', 56123))
while True:
    print(s.recv(1024).decode())
    time.sleep(5)

JS client code:
const ws = new WebSocket('wss://server.com:56123');
ws.onmessage = (msg) => {
    console.log(`Live users: ${msg.data}`);
};
ws.onerror = (err) => {
    console.error(err);
}
setTimeout(() => {
    console.log('ok')
}, 1000);

JS client error:
ErrorEvent {
  type: 'error',
  defaultPrevented: false,
  cancelable: false,
  timeStamp: 2791.141283
}

I originally intend to use this JS code to show the count on a HTML site. When I did that I got the following error:
WebSocket connection to 'wss://server.com:56123/' failed:


Your problem is that you are creating a regular network socket in Python and are trying to connect to it through the JS client as if it is a WebSocket, WebSockets are not the same as sockets and are not compatible with each other. You can fix this by instead using a WebSocket server in Python using the WebSocket library for both the server and client. e.g:
import websockets

https://pypi.org/project/websockets/
